show value of product selected when button clicked?
How to show product added or removed when add or remove button is clicked?
Right now i have to pass the id of caption to get the text content. But this way i have to create same function for all products.
how to make it dynamic for every product?


document.querySelectorAll(".addProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    const proName = document.getElementById("flower-caption").textContent;

    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Added.`;
  });
});
document.querySelectorAll(".removeProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
    const proName = document.getElementById("flower-caption").textContent;

    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Removed.`;
  });
});
<div class="product">
  <figure id="caption">
    <img src="images/flower.png" alt="Flowers" />
    <figcaption id="flower-caption">Beautiful Flower</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct">Add To Cart</button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct">Remove From Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <figure id="caption">
    <img src="images/parrot.png" alt="Parrot" />
    <figcaption id="parrot-caption">parrot</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct">Add To Cart</button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct">Remove From Cart</button>
</div>




To make your code work for all products without writing separate functions, you can adjust your event handlers to automatically find the product name when a button is clicked.

Use unique identifiers: Each HTML element should have a unique ID. For elements that repeat, like product names, use classes instead of IDs.

Update your event listeners: Change your code so that when a button is clicked, it looks for the nearest product container and grabs the product name from there. This way, no matter which button you click, the code always finds and displays the right product name.


document.querySelectorAll(".addProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const productElement = btn.closest(".product");
    const proName = productElement.querySelector("figcaption").textContent;
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Added.`;
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll(".removeProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const productElement = btn.closest(".product");
    const proName = productElement.querySelector("figcaption").textContent;
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Removed.`;
  });
});



Use parentNode to get the parent of clicked btn, then select figcaption's text.
id should be unique in html, you can use class instead.
<figure class="caption">



document.querySelectorAll(".addProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", ({
    target
  }) => {
    const proName = target.parentNode.querySelector("figcaption").textContent;
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Added.`;
  });
});
document.querySelectorAll(".removeProduct").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", ({
    target
  }) => {
    const proName = target.parentNode.querySelector("figcaption").textContent;
    document.getElementById("message").textContent = `${proName} Removed.`;
  });
});
<div class="product">
  <figure class="caption">
    <img src="images/flower.png" alt="Flowers" />
    <figcaption id="flower-caption">Beautiful Flower</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct">Add To Cart</button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct">Remove From Cart</button>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <figure class="caption">
    <img src="images/parrot.png" alt="Parrot" />
    <figcaption id="parrot-caption">parrot</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct">Add To Cart</button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct">Remove From Cart</button>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>




Simpler way is using closest() method.
Alos you don't need to use any id. just use css syntax on .querySelector() method...
And (that's true) id must be unique on a web page


const msgElm = document.querySelector('#message');

document.querySelectorAll('.addProduct, .removeProduct').forEach( btn => 
  {
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => 
    {
    let opMov   = btn.matches('.addProduct') ? 'Added' : 'Removed';
    let proName = btn.closest('.product')
                  .querySelector('figcaption').textContent;                 
 
    msgElm.textContent = `${proName} ${opMov}.`;
  });
});
<div class="product">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/flower.png" alt="Flowers" />
    <figcaption>Beautiful Flower</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct"    > Add To Cart      </button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct" > Remove From Cart </button>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/parrot.png" alt="Parrot" />
    <figcaption>parrot</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <button type="button" class="addProduct"    > Add To Cart      </button>
  <button type="button" class="removeProduct" > Remove From Cart </button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="message"></div>



